# Updating ResultSet using another java Class

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am still learning ResultSet and I was trying to update a ResultSet using another class, but then I was prompted an error. The error is

"This result set must come from a statement that was created with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select only one table, can not use functions and must select all primary keys from that table.".

My statement is working, and it is in ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE mode. Here's my sample code:

> Statement Class:

```
public abstract class Statements extends mysqlConnect {
     static Statement stmt;
     static ResultSet patient_details;
     String sql=null;

     public void getProfileDetails(String name) throws SQLException{

       stmt = con.createStatement(CONCUR_UPDATABLE, TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE);
       sql="select patient_id, last_name, first_name, middle_name, age, birthdate, gender, height, weight, blood_type, office_location, added_by, picture
            from patient_table
            where concat(last_name, \", \", first_name, \" \", middle_name )
            like '"+name+"%';";
       patient_details = stmt.executeQuery(sql);   }//getProfileDetails
```

> Controller class:

```
public class Controller extends Statements{

    void setLastName(String ln) throws SQLException{
     patient_details.absolute(patient_details.getRow());
     patient_details.updateString("last_name", ln);
     patient_details.updateRow();
    }//setLastName

}//controller
```

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation on [***`Connection.createStatement(int, int)`***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement%28int,%20int%29)

Method signature is:

```
Statement createStatement( int resultSetType,
                           int resultSetConcurrency ) throws SQLException
```

> **Parameters**:
>   ***`resultSetType`*** - a result set type; one of
>   `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`,
>   `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, or
>   `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`
>
> ***`resultSetConcurrency`*** - a concurrency type; one of
>   `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY` or
>   `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`

But you have put *concurrency* type as first parameter.

**Change**:

```
stmt = con.createStatement( CONCUR_UPDATABLE, TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE );
```

**To**:

```
stmt = con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
```

Comment: Did you mean: con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );

Comment: @SamiKorhonen: Yes. I made a copy paste error. answer updated.